# Android: select Address pragmatically within string of text

Tags: android, text, copy, sms, auto

Hi,
Anyone know how to copy a street address pragmatically from an SMS msg?
E.g
From text msg, if sender includes street Address, auto highlight to select Address (copy address).

**EXAMPLE**
**Start selection** From SMS msg, if Numbers exist AND less then 7digits (phone number)  THEN Start copy-selection (at Numbers).
**End copy-selection** at actual street suffix. (using simple street suffix database).

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.